# Not able to compile WebRtc AppRTCDemo android application

Tags: android, webrtc, ninja, apprtcdemo

Not able to compile WebRtc AppRTCDemo Android application using Ninja tool.

I am following instructions as given in this [README](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/examples/android/README) file.

I run this command

`sudo ninja -C out/Debug AppRTCDemo`

But it gets stuck on following lines:

```
log: ninja version 0.1.3 initializing
log: magic group: gid=0 (root)
log: entering main loop
log: generating initial pid array..
log: now monitoring process activity
```

It never returns from this and I am not able to build the demo application.

Comment: If you still need it, I have maintained a complete tutorial to solve all the issues. You can also visit this reference article: [Compile_WebRTC_Library_For_Android](https://github.com/mail2chromium/Compile_WebRTC_Library_For_Android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this [example](http://simonguest.com/2013/08/06/building-a-webrtc-client-for-android/), i have tried it and work success fully.

Only need to make one change is the link provided in this example for gclient config command is older one. Follow your link gclient config http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

Also make sure that you have oracle jdk-6, other version creates issues while following the steps to get the native code