# WebRtc build for Android (AppRtcDemo)

Tags: android, build, compilation, webrtc, apprtcdemo

Does anyone currently know where I can find a working AppRtcDemo. I have tried:

1) Using https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts to build on Ubuntu 14.1 with Java 1.7.0_71 and it failed for various reasons.
    a) Failed to checkout completely.
    b) Compilation errors.

I have a snapshot of AppRtcDemo which I built 3 months ago and it is not currently compatible with the apprtc server. Google has changed things underneath.

Any pointers would help

Comment: not sure brother but maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/24720165/1147787

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is little outdated since the project is moving very fast.

Comment: Also see [here](http://blog.gaku.net/building-webrtc-for-android-on-mac/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this to fix my issue:

1) Checkout the code by myself.

2) https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions#Install_Java_JDK

3) Follow the steps in https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/talk/examples/android/README